# Is my test of opencv findfundamentalMat 's output reasonable?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am using 
    cv:findFundamentalMat(InputArray points1, InputArray points2, OutputArray mask, int method=FM_RANSAC,        double param1=3., double param2=0.99) to filter the outliers in the image keypoint pairs.

I test the API with 100 points pair test, I set the minDistance to 1.0, and the confidenceLevel to 1.0.

The output is as follows: the size of the inliers is 15, however when I draw the matching points of the inlier, one pair of the points is apparently not correct. The position of the point is the right image is shifted about half of the image width.

As I do not quite understand the algorithm inside the findFundamentalMat, my question is, as the fundamental matrix was fitted with these points, the above pair should certainly be considered as outlier.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for calculating fundamental matrix is this:

```
aFb=0
```

Where `a` and `b` are the corresponding points in two images. As the formula suggests, fundamental matrix, for a specific point `a` finds a line of possible answers in the second image:
[image: Fundamental Matrix]
So, the RANSAC algorithm may find a correspondent legit, despite the fact it's farther than it seems it should.

Apart from this, I believe the best way to remove those kind of outliers, is by finding the appropriate Homography matrix, as its formula supports what you're looking for:

```
Ha=b
```

Anyway, we should see your two images and your results, to say more about this happening.

Comment: I have changed the API to cvFindHomography, and it worked. Thank you very much for the clear explaining.